# Cannot download ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, packages, sudo, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Making my way through this guide right here. Currently running **Kinetic** on the **Raspbian Jessie Lite**, which itself is running on the **Raspberry Pi 3**. So I'm trying to complete the pre-requisite which is the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials
```

However, whenever I try to install this, I get the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials
```

`sudo` can't locate *ros-indigo* or *ros-jade* either. In terms of the `etc/apt/source.list.d/ros-latest.list`, I have:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main
```

I have done a `sudo update` and a `sudo upgrade`, but neither seems to work. I have noticed a lot of questions around with this problem, but can't seem to find a solution to my specific problem.

---

**Update**

After a suggestion from the two answers below, I have realised that I cannot use `sudo-apt-get install` on packages when I have built *ROS-Kinetic* from source. Now, I have tried running the four commands:

```
rosinstall_generator ros_comm ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar >kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall 

rosinstall_generator ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar >kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall 

rosinstall_generator ros_comm ros_kinetic_ros_tutorials --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar >kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall 

rosinstall_generator ros_kinetic_ros_tutorials --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar >kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
```

But I still get the error: `The following not released packages stacks will be ignored: ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials`.
What exactly am I doing wrong in trying to build this from source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250738/cannot-download-ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) to install extra packages in ROS Kinetic in the raspberry pi 3. Read the page carefully.

**EDIT:**

What you need to run is the following:

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
rosinstall_generator ros_comm your_extra_packages --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
wstool merge -t src kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall
wstool update -t src
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r --os=debian:jessie
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

which from what I see, you probably tried it.

Ensure that the ROS repository is up to date, by following once again:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential cmake
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

and then try the installation again. Also try to install another package for example ros_control and see if this works and the problem is only related to ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-27**:
As mentioned in the comment by *ahendrix* in his answer below:

*"The ros-kinetic part of the apt package name is not part of the ROS package name. The ROS package is named ros_tutorials."*

**Comment by [jlzaphoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/54848/jlzaphoid/) on 2020-05-12**:
I've been battling with the same issue, and I'm personally attempting to install this package on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian (debian: buster). In the installation guide shown [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi), it's stated that rospack uses libboost1.58, rather than the automatically installed libboost1.67. Upon initial setup, the instructions prove to be correct and allow successful installation. at the moment you invoke

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r --os=debian:jessie'
```

after merging with wstool, libboost1.67 is installed again and creates more errors when building the catkin workspace. I believe that the package "ros_tutorials" is dependent on libboost1.67, which creates serious conflict.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which install guide did you follow when installing ROS?

If you installed from APT, it's possible that those packages aren't released for ARM.

If you installed from source, you'll need to install the tutorials from source too.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-26**:
Any links to where I can get these tutorials from source? I installed from source.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-26**:
[This](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) was where I installed from. As *patrichri* suggests, I tried using the same guide to build it from source, but that seems to have failed. please look at the **Update** section in my question above.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-27**:
The `ros-kinetic` part of the apt package name is not part of the ROS package name. The ROS package is named `ros_tutorials`.